# Dropdown menu with Material UI and Hooks doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-hooks

I'm trying to use React Hooks and Material UI to create a simple select tag but can't figure out how to set the value for the selected item in the menu.

I managed to get the menu items from the hooks array but as soon as I select one the code breaks.

```
const [values, setValues] = React.useState([
    "Bam",
    "Kate",
    "Nicole",
    "Aaron"
  ]);

  function handleChange(event) {
    setValues(oldValues => ({
      ...oldValues,
      [event.target.value]: event.target.value
    }));
  }
```

```
            <FormControl className={classes.formControl}>
              <InputLabel htmlFor="agent-simple">Agent</InputLabel>
              <Select
                value={values.value}
                onChange={handleChange}
                inputProps={{
                  name: "agent",
                  id: "age-simple"
                }}
              >
                {values.map((value, index) => {
                  return <MenuItem value={value}>{value}</MenuItem>;
                })}
              </Select>
            </FormControl>
```

I get this error `TypeError: values.map is not a function`

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Hi bamerf, just wrote you a solution, let me know if that helps and check out the sandbox :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TypeError: values.map is not a function` - that means your state is no longer an array. Your `handleChange` function is turning the state into an object.

It seems like what you actually need is to have an additional state to keep track of, specifically for the selected item. There is no need to mutate the original state array.

Try adding another `useState()`:

```
const [selected, setSelected] = useState("Bam")
```

Then update your `handleChange` function to update that state:

```
  function handleChange(event) {
     setSelected(event.target.value)
  }
```

Lastly connect the `Select` tags `value` attribute to the `selected state`:

```
  <FormControl className={classes.formControl}>
     <InputLabel htmlFor="agent-simple">Agent</InputLabel>
       <Select
          value={selected}
          onChange={handleChange}
          inputProps={{
           name: "agent",
            id: "age-simple"
          }}
        >
         {values.map((value, index) => {
            return <MenuItem value={value}>{value}</MenuItem>;
         })}
       </Select>
  </FormControl>
```

See working codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-wave-z133o